# Animated video editor on Mac

Tags: osx, video-editing

I am looking for a video editor, in which animated video can be created to advertise, introduce, explain how my iOS application works, explain benefit of an app like a cartoons or comics.

Comment: I recommend a combination of:
Final Cut Pro or Adobe Premiere for the video. Comic Life to make the graphics look like a comic book.

Comment: Any budget to be considered – or is money irrelevant at all? ;) What specific features do you need? By "animated video" you mean something like Comics? A few more details might help to good answers here ;)